# How do I see what item in the list the user has selected in a listview?

Tags: android, listview

In this image the user is shown a list. The user can search for an item in the list and click on it. How do I log what the user has clicked?

[image]

**Flight_Book.java :**

```
public class Flight_Book extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView lv;
SearchView sv;
String[] teams = {"Dog","Cat","Horse","Rabbit","Squirrel"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_flight__book);

    lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);
    sv = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchview1);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, teams);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {

            adapter.getFilter().filter(text);
            return false;
        }
    });


}
```

}

Comment: What has clicking an item in the listview to do with the searchview? It seems you do not use an onItemClickListener?

Comment: What do you mean exactly with logging? Where do you want to log? In a file?

Comment: `How do I see what item in the list the user has selected in a searchview?`??? Question does not make sense as one cannot select an item in a searchview as a searchview has no items.

Comment: @greenapps i'm sorry i meant listview

Comment: Ok. But what has all to do with a searchview? Nothing i think. So why are you talking about one?

Answer (score 0):

Your listview and searchView are completely different. If you are talking about suggestions,

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html

Try the method described in the link above and you'll be doing just fine.